In what order should I read Greg Iles's books?
What's the chronological order I should read Greg Iles's books with, especially the Mississippi and Penn Cage book series? On one of his interviews he said the following:

If you have just read Turning Angel, you should next read The Quiet
Game, the novel in which Penn Cage first appeared, and which many
readers believe is my best book. Blood Memory was written before
Turning Angel, and Penn’s father Tom Cage appears there in a
supporting role, but I would read “Blood Memory” after “The Quiet
Game,” not before. You will appreciate Tom much more then.

Greg is saying to read book #2 of Penn Cage before book #1. Further he says to read blood memory (Mississippi #5) after the quiet game (Penn Cage #1). It’s a mess.
